# USB Headset not working

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, drivers

OS - Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
Laptop - Lenovo X1 Carbon
Headset - Microsoft LifeChat LX-6000

Here's the deal- I have a usb headset.  When I first plug it in, or start the computer, it works fine. If I unplug the headset, sounds plays from my internal laptop speakers just fine. Then, if I plug the headset back in, it no longer works.

A few notes:

1. This issue persists for other headsets from other manufacturers.
2. This issue persists for different usb ports.
3. The headset works fine on other machines.
4. The headset appears as the "Default Device" when I go to "Manage Audio Devices"
5. When I play sounds- the green bars light up on "Manage Audio Devices"
6. If I go to Device Manager and go to the headset, it says "This device is working properly."
7. If I go to Device Manager and try to Update Driver..., it says the driver is up to date.
8. If I uninstall the driver, then plug the device back in- it re-installs the driver and then the device works.  But then if I unplug and re-plug it in, it doesn't work again.
9. Other devices work fine in the same usb port.

Comment: The driver is buggy, or the USB circuitry on your motherboard has malfunctioned, maybe a leaked capacitor somewhere. My bet is on the former. The latter is unlikely to cause such graceful/slight failure.

Comment: Yeah- that seems like the most likely issue :(

Comment: One other possibility, though even less likely than the other two, is that the USB device that is causing problems is drawing more power than the USB circuitry can supply. This theory can be tested by hooking a powered USB hub up to your system, and the problematic USB device up to the hub. A powered USB hub should be able to supply sufficient power, and the problem should disappear. But seeing as how the device is a headset, I find this exceedingly unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the firmware worked for me. It is available on the Microsoft homepage:

https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/de-de/business/lifechat-lx-6000-for-business/7xf-00001#techspecs-connect

Available on the LifeChat LX-6000 For Business product page under downloads, in case the Link ceases to work.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the firmware did not work for me.  The headset will work for a few seconds or minutes and then stop.  Sometimes they become unrecognized in Device manager.  Sometimes they show up as "USB Audio Device" and I can't get it to recognize them as LifeChat.  I've updated the firmware.  There seems to be no fix.